# Create template for grid and label

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates

I'm a beginner in c# WPF and i'm confuse, i can not create a template as I want.

I want to create a template for a grid element that can be apply for the labels inside.

Here is my code :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="GridTemplate">
        <Grid Height="24" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush
                    EndPoint="0.5,1" 
                    MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" 
                    StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF674797" Offset="0.8"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Label Height="34"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="26,-3,0,0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Width="Auto"
                    Foreground="White"
                    FontSize="16"
                    FontFamily="Calibri" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="gridBar">
    <DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" Template="{StaticResource GridTemplate}"/>
    <Label Content="My title" x:Name="labelAppName"/>
</Grid>
```

With that code I have the right Background color for my `grid` but the `label` is the default label.

Maybe I should use `Style` instead of `ControlTemplate` but I don't know the different and how to use it.

Thanks for help

EDIT: I'll to describe that I want.

I want to create a title bar (a grid) with a specific background color. I also want to create a title in that grid with a specific color by using label element.

I had many windows in my application and I want the same style/color for each title. So I wonder if I can create a template to not rewrite the code for each title bar.

I hope that I'm more clear this time, sorry for my horrible skill in English

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Try to explain it clearly. You can create two different styles for `Grid` and for `Label` (to have their properties set in default values as you like). But maybe you think about reusing a group of controls? Then data template + MVVM is the way to go. Though you can go out with `UserControl` and some dependency properties.

Comment: Or at least post a screen shot (inline) of desired effect? You have a `Label` in control template as well as `gridBar`. It is not clear which `Label` you are talking about.